# Finding all the views including the same action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, strong-parameters

There is a controller action with an *unprotected mass assignment*, where I want to implement strong parameters in. 
**In case that there are *multiple* views sending parameters to this action, how can I find them all?**

Comment: do you need to find all parameters and to whitelist them with strong parameters or what? please explain more clearly

Comment: Yes.

for example:
'view1' has a form asking for parameter 'name', and it is submitted to action 'update'.
'view2' has a form asking for parameter 'email', and it is submitted to the same action 'update'.
so I need to whitelist 'name' but not 'email' if it was submitted by 'view 1', and I need to whitelist 'email' but not 'name' if it was submitted by 'view 2'

I want to make sure that I haven't missed any case

Comment: do this form pages have different urls in aplication?

Comment: yes. they have different urls in aplication

Comment: Perhaps you might be better off creating different actions for different sources. This way you won't incorrectly mix logic, and you will be 100% sure each endpoint is being well validated.

Comment: I assume this is a legacy app that you don't know much about but have been tasked with making secure. Do you have access to server logs that you could concat and filter, looking for requests to just this action? Might get messy!

Comment: @Obversity Yes. I didn't write the code, and I need to make it secure.
I have access to server logs.
I am looking to find all the views sending parameters to any action I want to investigate